# Finding the dot product

Tags: r, dot-product

I have a set of vectors, `l`:

```
l <- list(c(1,0), c(0,1))
```

and vector `v`:

```
v <- c(2,2)
```

Say I want to find the dot product between the first vector in l and vector v, then the code should be:

```
l[1] %*% v
```

yet I get the following error:

> Error in l[1] %*% v : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

if I create a new vector containing the first vector in L, the dot product executes properly. What am I doing wrong for `l[1]` to not work?

```
l1 <- l[1]

l1 %*% v # = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to extract the `list` element with `[[` as `l[1]` is still a `list` with one element

```
l[[1]] %*% v
     [,1]
[1,]    2
```

---

To do this on all the elements,

```
lapply(l, `%*%`, v)
[[1]]
     [,1]
[1,]    2

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    2
```